# Selenium webdriver - Unable to locate element on modal dialog

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, modal-dialog

I cant locate a button on dialog pages, I tried to use cssselectors, xpaths, but simple i cant locate buttons/texts on modal dialogs.

I attached a screenshot from the code.

What can you recommend?

Thank you!

[image: Source]

Comment: Show exact selectors u used

Comment: Can you share html code? not picture

Comment: tried this 'driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button.btn.btn-default"))', By.xpath("//button[text()='Submit')
By.cssSelector("[type^='button']")
tried with absolute path /html/body/div[6]/div/div/div[3]/button, but its also doesnt work.

Comment: Sorry, By.cssSelector("button.btn.btn-default") this can locate it, but i can't click on it. Should i try to locate the Text on the button, and after that click on it?

Comment: @Heyjava : What error are you getting while clicking on the button?

Comment: @KunduK Zero, just the clicking command not happening, when I use this :By.cssSelector("button.btn.btn-default")

Comment: @Heyjava : So you are not getting any error on console?However it is not clicking right.

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Comment: Found the solution, it was a frame problem. This was on out of the visible frame id-s, had to switch to default content, btw thank all

Comment: @Heyjava can you please share your solution here with snippets as and answer to this question. I had a similar encounter. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I presume you are able to identify the element.However unable to click on that.
Try use following options.

1. Use `WebDriverWait` and `elementToBeClickable` to click on the element.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
WebElement elementBtn = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div.modal-footer button.btn.btn-default")));
elementBtn.click();
```

2. Use Action class to click on the element.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
WebElement elementBtn = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div.modal-footer button.btn.btn-default")));
Actions action=new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(elementBtn).click().build().perform();
```

3. Java Script Executor to click on the element.

```
JavascriptExecutor js= (JavascriptExecutor) driver; 
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.modal-footer button.btn.btn-default")));
```

**Note**: If above all options doesn't work.Check if there any `iframe` avaialable.If so, you need to switch to iframe first.like below.

```
driver.switchTo().frame("framename"); //name of the iframe.
driver.switchTo().frame(0); //you can use index as well.
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
        JavascriptExecutor js= (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        WebElement webElement=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.modal-footer button.btn.btn-default"));
        js.executeScript(“arguments[0].click()”, webElement);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
By.xpath(".//button[.='/"Submit/"'])
```

or

```
By.xpath(".//button[@class='btn btn-default'])
```

If it found but click doesnt work try that javascript from other comment

Answer (score 0):

Try the bellow `xpath`:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='modal-footer']//button[contains(@class,'btn-default')]")).click();
```